# Strategies to prevent duplicate data in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, duplicates, etl, business-intelligence, sql-data-warehouse

At the moment I am setting up an Azure SQL Data Warehouse. I am using Databricks for the ETL process with JSON-files from Azure Blob Storage.

**What is the best practice to make sure to not import duplicate dimensions or facts into the Azure SQL Data Warehouse?**

This could happen for facts e.g. in the case of en exception while the loading process. And for dimensions this could happen as well if I would not check, which data already exists.
I am using the following code to import data into the data warehouse and I found no "mode" which would only import data which not already exists:

```
spark.conf.set(
   "spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat",
   "true")

 renamedColumnsDf.write
     .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
     .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall)
     .option("dbtable", "SampleTable")
     .option( "forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True")
     .option("tempdir", tempDir)
     .mode("overwrite")
     .save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingest to a staging table, then CTAS to your fact table with a NOT EXISTS clause to eliminate duplicates.